# Unable to merge dex - android studio

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am developing an app that stores data on an AWS DynamoDB table, But I keep getting the following error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

these are my gradle files:
[image]

I would really appreciate if someone takes the time to please help me out.

Comment: Please use code instead of image for your build.gradle. Regarding the problem, you need to use multidex. But it is better if you not using all the amazon library, because it's huge. Afaik, you don't need android-sdk-s3 library for using AWS DynamoDB. cmiiw.

Comment: I added the exact set of dependencies you have in build.gradle and ran the gradle task transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug and didn't have any issues. Can you check if you have any external libs (.jar/.aar) under libs directory in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in your App base gradle file for more info refer [link](http://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) , i hope this will solve your problem.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

`dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}`